# How to start a package.json script in pm2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, pm2, yarnpkg

I want to demonise my express js graphql api server. In windows local dev, I can start my server by running this command and it works fine:

`yarn dev`

This start command is defined in my `package.json` like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development DEBUG=express:* nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js"
  },
```

When I try to start this in pm2 in my linux server, I get a success like this:

```
latheesan@app:~/apps/tweet/server$ pm2 start yarn -- dev
[PM2] Starting /usr/bin/yarn in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

However, when I type `pm2 status` it says error and also the display looks really odd:

[image]

I am running this on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

If I don't use the `pm2` and just start the app in my ubuntu server with `yarn dev` - it runs fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nodemon has been able to watch file changes and restart server, so maybe you don't need use pm2?

Comment: Yes I realize that now. I am trying to put together a json config for the pm2 minus the Nodemon.

Answer (score 2):

Pm2 now support npm

```
$ pm2 start --interpreter babel-node server.js
```

**(or)**

```
$ pm2 start npm --start
```

**(or)**

```
$ pm2 start npm --name "myAPP" --start
```

**(or)**

```
$ pm2 start npm --name "{app_name}" --run "{script_name}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have now resolved this issue.

Install the `babel-node` globally via: `npm install -g babel-cli`

Then create the pm2 config in json: *pm2.json*

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "Tweet GraphQL Server",
            "exec_interpreter": "babel-node",
            "script": "index.js",
            "merge_logs": true,
            "cwd": "./src",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I can run this command to start the pm2 process: `pm2 start pm2.json`

Answer (score 0):

i do this in my app like this:

in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "... start application script ...",
    "start:dev": "... start application script as development mode ...",
    "pm2": "pm2 start npm --name \"CustomeNameForPM2\" -- run start --watch",
    "pm2:dev": "pm2 start npm --name \"CustomeNameForPM2\" -- run start:dev --watch"
}
```

now you can run pm2 easy with `npm run pm2` or npm run `pm2:dev`

but if you like to do something better, you can read pm2 documentation and use [pm2 ecosystem config file](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)